# Python install ,when make, dead loop " The Makefile was updated, you may need to re-run make."

Tags: python, makefile, installation

The system is Centos7 ,I  would like to install python2.7.9 (default python2.7.5 installed in Centos7).
When 'make', occur following error,and loops

```
The Makefile was updated, you may need to re-run make.
/bin/sh ./Modules/makesetup -c ./Modules/config.c.in \
                        -s Modules \
                        Modules/Setup.config \
                        Modules/Setup.local \
                        Modules/Setup
```

and I don't know how to solve it. Have Somebody idea about it.

Answer (score 0):

haha.It's solved.Just to have a sleep.Just joke!
when 'make',let it go ahead ,not to interupt it.
 maybe you want to wait the moment that the task finished,need make several hours,so you just have a sleep.